# Bing maps - how can I turn off street labels in Bird's Eye view?

Tags: bing-maps

For a client I need to show a static Bing map, in Bird's Eye view, with the street labels turned off.  I can accomplish Bird's Eye view with no labels for *dynamic* view by just clicking the toolbar buttons for Bird's Eye view and labels off.  But my goal is to show this for a *static* map, on load, without the need to click any buttons.

Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm putting everything in the `<body>` for demonstration purposes. You'd probably put the loading of the external `mapcontrol` library and your `GetMap()` function in the `<head>`. You might even want to put your own script in an external file.

```
<body onload="GetMap();">
<div id='myMap' style="position:relative; width:400px; height:400px;"></div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ecn.dev.virtualearth.net/mapcontrol/mapcontrol.ashx?v=6.2"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var map = null;

function GetMap() {
    map = new VEMap('myMap');
    map.LoadMap(new VELatLong(47.6, -122.33), 10, VEMapStyle.Birdseye, false);
}   
</script>
</body>
```

The parameters for [VEMap.LoadMap(*VELatLong*, *zoom*, *style*, *fixed*, *mode*, *showSwitch*, *tileBuffer*, *mapOptions*)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb412546.aspx) are:

*VELatLong* A VELatLong Class object that represents the center of the map. Optional.

*zoom* The zoom level to display. Valid values range from 1 through 19. Optional. Default is 4. **Note that *VEMapStyle.Birdseye* seems to only support two zoom levels: 1 gives you the wide view, anything else gives you the close-up view.**

*style* A VEMapStyle Enumeration value specifying the map style. Optional. Default is VEMapStyle.Road. **I changed this to *VEMapStyle.Birdseye*** as documented at *[VEMapStyle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb412515.aspx)*.

*fixed* A Boolean value that specifies whether the map view is displayed as a fixed map that the user cannot change. Optional. Default is false.

*mode* A VEMapMode Enumeration value that specifies whether to load the map in 2D or 3D mode. Optional. Default is VEMapMode.Mode2D.

*showSwitch* A Boolean value that specifies whether to show the map mode switch on the dashboard control. Optional. Default is true (the switch is displayed).

*tileBuffer* How much tile buffer to use when loading map. Default is 0 (do not load an extra boundary of tiles). This parameter is ignored in 3D mode.

*mapOptions* A VEMapOptions Class that specifies other map options to set.

---

Lastly, the [Bing Maps Interactive SDK](http://www.microsoft.com/maps/isdk/ajax/) is a great resource for playing around and trying to figure out how things work and the [Bing Map Control Class Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb429565.aspx) documents the entire API.

Comment: Thanks for the help.  It turns out i was using 'b' in place of VEMapStyle.Birdseye, which produced a VEMapStyle.BirdseyeHybrid.  I should have shown my code!

Answer (score -3):

The drop down menu that you pick either Birds Eye or Aerial from has a tick box under it saying "Show labels"

Simply untick it

Comment: I think you misunderstood the question. It is developer's question (eg How to implement...) and not an end user question.