# Bing Maps AJAX Control 7.0 - how can I turn off street labels in Bird's Eye view?

Tags: bing-maps

I use Bing Maps AJAX Control 7.0 ISDK.

I would like to turn off the street labels in Bird's Eye view.

[The question has been asked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1446323/bing-maps-how-can-i-turn-off-street-labels-in-birds-eye-view) but for the api 6

I can do it with the navigation bar.

But the navigation bar is off on my map :

```
showDashboard: false
```

I don't find any solution on the sdk :

http://www.bingmapsportal.com/isdk/ajaxv7#CreateMapWithViewOptions7

Here is my code :

```
function handlerEvent() 
{ 
     displayAlert('Handler clicked'); 
} 
Microsoft.Maps.loadModule('Microsoft.Maps.Themes.BingTheme', { callback: function() 
{
    map = new Microsoft.Maps.Map(document.getElementById('bingMap'), 
{ 
     credentials: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx', 
     theme: new Microsoft.Maps.Themes.BingTheme(),
     center: new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.219058,-1.553625),
     mapTypeId: Microsoft.Maps.MapTypeId.birdseye,
     zoom: 16,
     showDashboard: false
}); 
var infoboxOptions = {title:'Text', description:'TextTextText', actions:[{label: 'Click Handler', eventHandler: handlerEvent}]}; 
map.entities.push(new Microsoft.Maps.Infobox(map.getCenter(), infoboxOptions)); 
}});
```

Can you help me do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add this option

labelOverlay : Microsoft.Maps.LabelOverlay.hidden

Comment: Thank you, labelOverlay is what i need.